# Establishing how good my ipad's wifi connection is

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, wifi

I am writing an iPad app that uses wifi to transfer data. I use the following to establish if there is internet connection:

```
- (BOOL)connectedToInternet
{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error: NULL];
return ([response statusCode] == 200) ? YES : NO;
}
```

Is there a method to help me find how good my ipad's wifi connection is?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Reachability` class? It's a nice feature to get info about internet connection via either Wi-Fi or 3G. You couldn't detect a quality of your connection, but there are few useful methods to detect connection states.
Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) source.